# how to develop custom interface in LWC or any alternate of <Aura:interface in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, interface

In our project aura:interface is using to render data from multiple child aura:component, now we want to include LWC component as well as child component. Is there any way to implement similar flow as aura:interface in LWC.

Any suggestion or reference will be helpful.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Downvoters: really? This isn't a well-documented question anywhere in the LWC documentation that I know of, so it'd make sense to have it here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you use the `extends` keyword in your controller:

```
import ParentComponent from 'c/parentComponent';
export default class ChildComponent extends ParentComponent {
}
```

All of the properties and methods from the parent are accessible. You can override properties and methods by redefining them in `ChildComponent`. If you do not provide a `.html` file, it will inherit the template from `ParentComponent` automatically.

Comment: Thanks for this approach, can we use this  component in aura component? as at the end we need to combine all child components(aura and LWC) data in one response.

Comment: @ShilpaJain It's possible I misread your question, based on this comment. Aura can extend other Aura components, and LWC can extend other LWC components. You can't mix the two, and you can't switch between Aura and LWC; once you're in LWC, it must be LWC all the way down.